# Cannot Install Delve Go Debugger on Mac

Tags: bash, debugging, go, delve

I am trying to follow along with the following YouTube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qFf2PRSfBlQ) on getting started with Go Debugging.

It recommends following the Delve installation instructions on the official Delve github repo. For Mac users, they are [as follows](https://github.com/go-delve/delve/blob/master/Documentation/installation/osx/install.md):

Making sure the toolchain is in place

```
xcode-select --install
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
```

Using "go get" to install Delve

```
go get -u github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv
```

Making sure developer mode is enabled in Xcode

```
sudo /usr/sbin/DevToolsSecurity -enable
Developer mode is already enabled.
```

To check that the installation has been completed correctly, I tried running the following in my Go project directlry:

```
dlv debug
zsh: command not found: dlv
```

The author of the video tutorial recommends updating GOPATH and PATH variables in the `~/.bash_profile` file in the case that the command is not recognized. I did so so by adding:

```
export GOPATH=/Users/<user_name>/go/src/
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/<user_name/go/src/my_project
```

However, even after doing so, I get the same result when trying to run the debugger:

```
dlv debug
zsh: command not found: dlv
```

Even if I change the shell for the default zsh to bash, using `exec bash`, I get the same result.

Answer (score 28):

In order to run an executable, it needs to be available in your `PATH`.

**1. Configure your path.**

Make sure that your `GOPATH` and `$GOPATH/bin` directories are set correctly in your shell environment. You can do this by adding the following lines to your shell configuration.

`~/.zshrc` if you're using `zsh`.

`~/.bash_profile` if you're using `bash`.

```
export GOPATH="$HOME/go"
export PATH="$GOPATH/bin:$PATH"
```

---

**2. Re-load your shell configuration.**

Make sure to either restart your shell or run `source` on your shell configuration file after the changes:

`source ~/.zshrc` if you're using `zsh`.

`source ~/.bash_profile` if you're using `bash`.

---

**3. Install the `dlv` package.**

```
go install github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv
```

This is assuming that you're using `/Users/<username>/go` as your `GOPATH`.

---

You should now be able to run `dlv` from your terminal session.

Good luck!

Comment: what is the purpose of the semi-colon at the end of the second line?

Comment: Followed the steps you suggested, both with and without the semi-colon. Still getting the same result ```zsh: command not found: dlv```

Comment: Sorry, the `;`is a typo. You can leave it out. I will edit the post.

Comment: After you run the `go install`, is the executable inside `$GOPATH/bin`?

Comment: If you have added `$GOPATH/bin` to your `PATH`, and the executable is in `$GOPATH/bin` - I'm not sure why you're getting troubles. Are you sure you are editing the correct shell config? i.e. `.zshrc` if you're using `ZSH` and `.bash_profile` if you're using `bash`.

Comment: I've only edited ```.bash_profile```. Then I tried running it from both ```bash``` and ```zsh```, switching between the two with the ```exec``` command.

Comment: If `zsh` is your main shell, then rather add the lines into your `~/.zshrc` file. If you're wanting to use bash, then use `chsh` to change your default shell to `bash` and restart your terminal session.

Comment: I haven't used `dlv` previously, as I usually debug using Goland. I just followed by own instructions and successfully debugged some tests that I'm having issues with using `dlv` - I'm using `zsh` and `Mac OS`.

Comment: This looks perfect, should work fine. (I have the same setup, MacOS and Zsh)

Comment: Following your updated instructions, I now get a new error message: ``` can'tload package: package .: no Go files in /Users/<user_name>/go/bin
exit status 1```

Comment: Did you replace `<user_name>` with your username?

Comment: Yes, I replaced user_name

Comment: Can you post the output of `echo $GOPATH` and `echo $PATH`?

Answer (score 10):

Set the environment variable `GOBIN` to be where you want the `dlv` binary to be installed.

For example:

```
GOBIN=~/bin go install github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv
```

This will install dlv in ~/bin

### Clarification

When you run `go install`, the installation path can be specified by setting the `GOBIN` environment variable.

There are two ways to set the environment variable:

1) Run `export GOBIN=<SOMETHING>` before you run `go install ..`

```
$ export GOBIN="$HOME/bin"
$ go install github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv
```

The export command will alter the environment in the current terminal session. Any later command you execute will see the value you set for `GOBIN`

When you go with this approach, you usually want to have this environment variable active not only in this session, but all future sessions as well. So it's better to add the line to your bash profile.

2) Set the environment variable only for the command.

```
$ A=10 some-command
```

In this case, `some-command` will see the value of the environment variable `A` set to '10'. If you run a later command, it will not see this value.

This approach is useful when you are just trying things out, or if you only want to set certain environment variables in certain situations.

The command line I provided as the answer follows this second approach.

It sets the GOBIN variable to the `~/bin` directory, and then invokes `go install` in the same line. This way, this invocation of `go install` will install dlv in `~/bin`

This of course assumes you have a `bin` directory in your home directory.

If you don't have such directory, then this will not work.

The idea is not to copy paste the line as is. The idea is to change `~/bin` to be the directory where you would like the `dlv` binary to be installed.

Comment: Should I write this as ```export GOBIN=~/...``` or just insert it as you have listed it in my ```source ~/.bash_profile```?

Comment: You can do it inline like I showed here without the export keyword. If you want it to always be set then you can add it to your  bash profile as `export GOBIN=~/bin`

Comment: After adding your line, with the ```export``` and then running ```source ~/.bash_profile```, I get the following error message: ```bash: export: `github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv': not a valid identifier ```

Comment: Define "basic understanding"?

Comment: In your bash profile, only put `export GOBIN=~/bin`. Don't put the `go install ..` as part of the `export` line.

Comment: I added some clarifications. Does it clear things up, or do you still have some confusions?

Comment: Looks like we are making some progress now. I am running ```dlv debug```` from my ```~./go/bin``` file, but I am getting the following errror: ```can't load package: package .: no Go files in /Users/<username>/go/bin exit status 1```. Despite the fact that I have several compiled go binaries in that folder.